# Prepend a ggplot2 object to a list of plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Suppose I have a list of plots `plotlist` and I want to call `patchwork::wrap_plots(plotlist)`.

I also want to prepend one more plot to the beginning of the list.

Let's start with a list that has 2 plots:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

cols <- c("mpg", "hp")

plot_col <- function(this_col) {
  ggplot(mtcars) +
    aes_string("wt", this_col) +
    geom_point()
}

plotlist <- lapply(cols, plot_col)
```

This works:

```r
res <- wrap_plots(plotlist)
```

But wait, I have one more plot.

```r
p <- plot_col("qsec")
```

Can I prepend the new plot `p` to `plotlist`?

None of these approaches work: `c()`, `list()`, `purrr::prepend()`

```r
newlist <- c(p, plotlist)
res <- wrap_plots(newlist)
#> Error: Only know how to add ggplots and/or grobs
```

```r
newlist <- list(p, plotlist)
res <- wrap_plots(newlist)
#> Error: Only know how to add ggplots and/or grobs
```

```r
newlist <- purrr::prepend(plotlist, p)
res <- wrap_plots(newlist)
#> Error: Only know how to add ggplots and/or grobs
```

Comment: You need `newlist <- c(list(p), plotlist)` to add `p` at the correct level.

Comment: In this case you might do `p + plotlist`

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the `c()` function with two lists (thanks to [Axeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4341440/axeman)):

```r
newlist <- c(list(p), plotlist)
res <- wrap_plots(newlist)
```

2. Use one of the many functions provided by the [rlist](https://github.com/renkun-ken/rlist) package to manipulate lists:

```r
# install.packages("rlist")
newlist <- rlist::list.prepend(plotlist, p)
res <- wrap_plots(newlist)
```

3. Or build a new list with a for loop:

```r
newlist <- list()
newlist[[1]] <- p
for (i in seq_along(plotlist)) {
  newlist[[i + 1]] <- plotlist[[i]]
}
res <- wrap_plots(newlist)
```